# how does JavaScript outerHTML function behave?

Tags: javascript, dom

I just started learning about DOM Web API and the behavior of outerHTML function seems a bit odd for me.

This is my code:

```
const heading = document.getElementById('heading');
heading.innerHTML = 'This is a <span>Heading</span>';
console.log(heading.innerHTML);
heading.outerHTML = '<h2>Hello World!</h2>';
console.log(heading.outerHTML);
```

Output:

```
This is a <span>Heading</span>
<h1 id="heading">This is a <span>Heading</span></h1>
```

For what I know DOM changes happen synchronously and therefore I expect the result for the second log to be `<h2>Hello World!</h2>` but the output is quite confusing.

Comment: Take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML

Comment: You cannot directly log the properties of `heading` once you replace it. Because the object is still the `heading` element. You have removed `heading` from the DOM and replaced it with a `h2`. But you did not re-point the **variable** to the new `h2` element. So instead of logging `heading.outerHTML` you need to `console.log(document.getElementByTagName('h2'))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok lets try to give an answer to that step by step.

- First, you get the elemnet 'heading' ID and assign it to the heading variable.
- Sets the innerHTML of the heading element ('This is a Head...)
- Log innerHTML of the heading element.
- Set outherHTML of heading element (Hello World!.. which replaces the heading element with th enew element in the DOM
- Log otherHTML of the heading element. **BUT** , heading element has been replaced in the DOM. OutherHTML property refers to the serialized HTML of the element as it was before, and that is why u see the original tag h1 in the output.

to get what you want, you could try to define a new variable using DOM:

```
const heading2 = document.getElementById('heading');
console.log(heading2.outerHTML);
```

this will give you the output ure looking for.